# How can I use "{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, " as a string on jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

It seems that "{" is problematic and jquery doesn´t take it as a string

I'm trying to use this function:

```
$('.attribute_list li a img').on('mouseover', function () {
var imahov = $(this).attr('alt');
$('a.jqzoom img').attr('src',  "{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, " + imahov + ", 'small_default')}");
});
```

But seems like the variable `imahov` is not taken as a variable and rather is taken as a string.

I tried separating them as variables instead, like this:

```
var imahov = $(this).attr("alt");
var prim = "{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, ";
var fin = ", 'small_default')}";
```

But variables prim and fin retrun errors, seems that the problem is the "{"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape those characters. Try this.

`$('a.jqzoom img').attr('src',  "\\{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, " + imahov + ", 'small_default')\\}";)`

Make sure you use `\\` <- two backslashes

and not just one.

You also might need to escape the `$` and `>`

Comment: I tried this as a test:

   `$('.attribute_list li a img').on('mouseover', function () {
    var prim = encodeURIComponent("{$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, ");
     alert(prim);
    });`

But it doesn´t even load the page

But it works if I delete the "{" which is the same issue

Comment: can you try with single quotes instead of double?